# Primefaces widget: how to check inheritance relationship like java instanceof?

Tags: inheritance, primefaces, widget

Primefaces widget: how to check inheritance relationship like java instanceof?

```
WidgetA
   |
WidgetB
   |
WidgetC
```

How to check if a widget is instance of any widget type in a hierarchy?
like java instanceof.

How to determine if a widget type is subtype of another widget type?

Comment: If a widget is of type B, it should be of type A.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the old fashioned way using `instanceof` in JavaScript...

```js
    // stop any PF pollers and idle monitors
    for (item in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
        widget = PrimeFaces.widgets[item];

        // stop all pollers
        if (widget instanceof PrimeFaces.widget.Poll) {
            widget.stop();
        }

        // stop idle monitor
        if (widget instanceof PrimeFaces.widget.IdleMonitor) {
            widget.pause();
        }
    }
```